# .htaccess rewrite in subdirectories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have wamp server installed and i can not rewrite my urls from a subdirectory

```
http://localhost/new1/articles/details.php?name=test
```

to

```
http://localhost/new1/articles/test
```

i tried like this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^new1/articles/(.*)/$ /new1/articles/details.php?name=$1 [L,R=301]
```

and this

```
RewriteCond /articles/ -d
RewriteRule ^/articles/([^/]*)  /articles/details.php?name=$1
```

Nothing works...i get 404 not found.
what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this rule in `/new1/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new1/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]+)/?$ articles/details.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```